# Can I use Swift to list all apps that are currently running?

Tags: ios, iphone, arrays, swift

Am I able to use Swift code to display all apps that are currently running on an Iphone (or Ipad)? I am hoping to integrate this with an "on/off" button, but am having trouble getting the display to appear.

Answer (score 3):

No. The lists of installed and running applications are treated as private data, and are not available to applications. [Apple has specifically rejected applications for attempting to determine what other applications were installed on a user's phone.](https://github.com/danielamitay/iHasApp/issues/34)